# Guardar trayecto en MySQL POINT

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, geolocalización

Necesito guardar un trayecto completo establecido por **GeoPuntos** (`POINT`) en [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) para poder visualizarse en una aplicación [android](/questions/tagged/android) por medio de Google Maps.

De momento ya pude obtener estas ubicaciones y guardarlas con **latitud y longitud** en la base de datos por medio del tipo de dato `POINT` y sin problema.

Mi duda es saber si existe una forma de guardar un arreglo de datos para no guardar 30 filas de un solo trayecto en la Base de Datos y guardar solo una fila.

Answer (score 1):

En [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) desde la versión 5.6, tiene funciones de geolocalizacion, puedes usar un tipo POLYGON, recibe la cantidad de coordenadas que quieras pasarle ejemplo:

> POLYGON ((-75.57381551 6.25798087,-75.57918235 6.24777741,-75.57440132
>   6.234515846,-75.57946533 6.196375053,-75.58360264 6.18617211,-75.60424492 6.162620258,-75.631635636057197 6.14764380890139,-75.638598650668399 6.15055592935419,-75.624286383400005 6.1564761251,-75.5952756107 6.1772549559,-75.58530182 6.188866026,-75.581181943399997 6.1982522933,-75.576439797904897 6.23223344905877,-75.58028542 6.244681524,-75.58208786 6.245897352,-75.58204494 6.250291376,-75.5803927 6.250909949,-75.57580076 6.258802026,-75.57381551 6.25798087))

Detalles del funcionamiento del campo [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-polygon-property-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ocupar el tipo de dato MULTIPOINT si lo que quieres es guardar varios puntos en un solo campo
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-multipoint.html